# How to get the keywords inside the category?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How to get the keywors inside the particular category using coreservice?

I am looking into the `CategoryData` class, but i dont see any methods or properties related to `Keyword`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Getting the Keywords inside a Category is similar to getting the Components inside a Folder. So you will have to call `GetListXml` with the category as the subject.

```cs
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
var category = "tcm:1-2-512";
var keywords = client.GetListXml(category, filter);
foreach (var keywordElement in keywords.Descendants())
{
    ...
}
```

---

***Some background***: the Core Service is a service-oriented API, so none of the `...Data` objects have any methods to load additional information. Instead all data access goes through the `CoreServiceClient`, which then returns data objects that contain... data.

For those with a Java background, these might be more familiar as DAO/DTO, Data Access Object and Data Transfer Object: the `CoreServiceClient` is the DAO, the `...Data` objects are the DTOs.